# Line number "off" case .tex file on Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

Is it possible turn off line number automatically when editing a .tex file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Language-specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings)

Edit the right (global/workspace) `settings.json`

```
  "[latex]": {
    "editor.lineNumbers": "off"
  }
```